# How to parse and read "_id" field from and to a pydantic model?

Tags: python, mongodb, pydantic

I am trying to parse MongoDB data to a pydantic schema but fail to read its `_id` field which seem to just disappear from the schema.
The issue is definitely related to the underscore in front of the object attribute. I can't change `_id` field name since that would imply not parsing the field at all.
Please find below the code I use (using `int` instead of `ObjectId` for the sake of simplification)

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User_1(BaseModel):
    _id: int

data_1 = {"_id": 1}

parsed_1 = User_1(**data_1)
print(parsed_1.schema())

class User_2(BaseModel):
    id: int

data_2 = {"id": 1}

parsed_2 = User_2(**data_2)
print(parsed_2.schema())
```

`User_1` is parsed successfully since its `_id` field is required but can't be read afterwards.
`User_2` works in the above example by fails if attached to Mongo which doesn't provide any `id` field but `_id`.

Output of the code above reads as follows:

```py
User_1  {'title': 'User_1', 'type': 'object', 'properties': {}}
User_2  {'title': 'User_2', 'type': 'object', 'properties': {'id': {'title': 'Id', 'type': 'integer'}}, 'required': ['id']}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you need to use an alias for that field name

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class User_1(BaseModel):
    id: int = Field(..., alias='_id')
```

See the docs [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/).

Comment: Thanks! For those who wish to convert an object back to dict containing the `_id`, just use `User_1(_id=1234).dict(by_alias=True)` so you end up with a dict having the `_id` key.

Comment: using `Field` didn't work, i used Config.fields instead

Answer (score 0):

I know that you had asked this ages ago, but for anyone else still struggling with it here's a suggested solution by [MongoDb](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/python/python-quickstart-fastapi/)

When applying their solution we get the following code.

```
from typing import Optional, Annotated
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, BeforeValidator

PyObjectId = Annotated[str, BeforeValidator(str)]

class User_1(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[PyObjectId] = Field(alias="_id", default=None)
```

All the validation and model conversions work just fine, without any class Config, or other workarounds. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers don't work for me, I don't know why. Maybe the versions are deprecated, here is the updated answer:

```
from pydantic import Field
from bson import ObjectId 
from typing import Optional

id: Optional[ObjectId] = Field(alias='_id')
title: str
cover: str

class Config:
    json_encoders = {
        ObjectId: str
    }
    arbitrary_types_allowed = True
```