# How to parse and read “_id” field from and to a pydantic model?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, class, objectid, pydantic

class User(BaseModel):

```
name : str
id : PydanticObjectId  = Field(None, alias='_id')
```

data = self.coll.find_one({"email": email})

```
        user = User(**data)
        return user
```

now when my data is returned from mongo db it is in the form of doc dictionary.
when I verify the elements of the user I can't find any field named as id. Why this is so?
If I replace the id from _id then also the same issue remains.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59562997/5320906)?

Answer (score 0):

I know that you had asked this ages ago, but for anyone else still struggling with it here's a suggested solution by [MongoDb](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/python/python-quickstart-fastapi/)

When applying their solution we get the following code.

```
from typing import Optional, Annotated
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, BeforeValidator

PyObjectId = Annotated[str, BeforeValidator(str)]

class User(BaseModel):
    name : str
    id: Optional[PyObjectId] = Field(alias="_id", default=None)
```

Now everything should work just as intended.